# Mongoid: Query for objects where value is a certain value or not set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm trying to query for all objects that match a set of fields, with not having that field set counts as matching.

For example, if I have these objects:

```
{"field1":"one", "field2":"two"}
{"field1":"two", "field2":"three"}
{"field1":"one"}
```

Then I would want something similar to `Objects.where(:field1 => "one", :field2 => "two")` that also matches the third object, in addition to the first. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The `$or` query operator

```
db.blah.find( { field1:"one"}, $or[{"field1":"one"}, {"field2":"two" } ] } )
```

This says find where field1=one, OR field1=one AND field2=two

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking for matching specifically on a field being absent. For example, I would want to match `{}` which your example does not do.

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand what you are trying to match now.  My way would match any records that had field1:"one", and you are looking to limit on the absence of field2.

Comment: Since Mongo is schema-less, I don't think it's possible, because it doesn't really what is "normal" for a document, each document in a collection is it's own schema.  Lay an ORM on top and you can.  Mongo doesn't know record three is missing something, it only knows what it has.